VS Powershell wont let me compile, but using it externally will
I'm currently using two different languages and having a similar issue on both. With Java the powershell within VS code isn't allowing me to compile using Javac, and I can't use GHCI for Haskell.
However, when i use the 'normal' powershell it is completely fine. Does anyone have any ideas why?
I get this error when i try to use these commands:
"ghci : The term 'ghci' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

ghci

  + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ghci:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException"




I get an identical one for Javac (minus the GHCI bit)

This is a PATH issue.  You don't have the correct directory for those commands on your path.

Can this answer solve your issue?

As mentioned in the comment, according to this answer, this is an issue about path.
You could set "terminal.integrated.cwd": "" to the path where you want your terminal open in your settings.json.
